# can I omit field creation if I need custom getter/setter?

Tags: c#

I can write such beatiful straightforward code:

```
 public int Delta { get; private set; }
```

Now I want to add just one call `OnPropertyChanged("Delta");`

This is the only way I know how to do that:

```
public int Delta { get { return _delta; } private set
{
    _delta = value; OnPropertyChanged("Delta"); }
}
private int _delta;
```

It's too much extra-code! Why should I introduce field in this case? Can you make this code shorter? I would like to have something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
 public int Delta { get; private set { OnPropertyChanged("Delta"); } }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot do this with auto-properties.  Auto-properties are meant to be short hand syntax for a property over a field.  They have virtually no other capabilities.  Any custom code execution requires a full fledged property.

Answer (score 3):

I created this code snippet for this purpose (example):

```
private string _Name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        if (_Name != value) {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>propn (Creates a notifying property)</Title>
      <Shortcut>propn</Shortcut>
      <Description>This snippet helps implementing INotifyPropertyChanged by creating a property with backing store. The settter calls OnPropertyChanged if the value changes. Use the "notify" code snippet in order to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.</Description>
      <Author>Olivier Jacot-Descombes</Author>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="false">
          <ID>classname</ID>
          <ToolTip>Name of class</ToolTip>
          <Default>ClassNamePlaceholder</Default>
          <Function>ClassName()</Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>NameOfProperty</ID>
          <ToolTip>
          </ToolTip>
          <Default>MyProp</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>Type</ID>
          <ToolTip>
          </ToolTip>
          <Default>int</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $Type$ _$NameOfProperty$;
public $Type$ $NameOfProperty$
{
    get { return _$NameOfProperty$; }
    set
    {
        if (_$NameOfProperty$ != value) {
            _$NameOfProperty$ = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("$NameOfProperty$");
        }
    }
}
]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Copy this code into a text file. Give it the extension ".snippet" and you can import it into Visual Studio by using the Code Snippet Manager (tools menu).

And here another snippet which creates the event handler (example):

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
//TODO: Inherit interface System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.
//TODO: Create properties with the propn code snippet.

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

#endregion
```

Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>notify (Implements INotifyPropertyChanged)</Title>
      <Shortcut>notify</Shortcut>
      <Description>This snippet the inserts the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation into a class</Description>
      <Author>Olivier Jacot-Descombes</Author>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="false">
          <ID>classname</ID>
          <ToolTip>Name of class</ToolTip>
          <Default>ClassNamePlaceholder</Default>
          <Function>ClassName()</Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
//TODO: Inherit interface System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.
//TODO: Create properties with the propn code snippet.

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

#endregion]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>
      </Title>
      <Shortcut>
      </Shortcut>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <Author>
      </Author>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: What these snippets do? Could you provide an C# example?

Comment: @sll: I added exmaples to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider it not being so beatiful! Refer to this blog post from Seeman: [Code Smell: Automatic Property](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/26/CodeSmellAutomaticProperty.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

.NET properties is a syntaxis sugar for the methods `type get_PropertyName()` and `set_PropertyName(type value)` which are generated under the hood, `get_` returns underlying field value and `set_` obviously updates it. So there are two options: either you provide own methods body by specifying property getter/setter or let it do by Framework by generating backing field for you, so there are no third case at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want simplify you `PropertyChanged` routine you could look at [notifypropertyweaver](http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver).

And after that your code will be look like:

```
[NotifyProperty(PerformEqualityCheck = false)]
public int Delta { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is the case. If you are using C# 4.0 you can use [dynamic object](http://codeflow49.blogspot.com/2010/06/automatic-inotifypropertychanged-with.html) and do it with lesser code at the expense of type safety.

In a nutshell you do

```
public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
{
    //set the actual  property and do
    OnPropertyChanged(binder.Name);      
}
```

There might be more code to write in **TrySetMember** but you can share it across multiple properties in the same class.

If you donot mind any third party frameworks, you can use a **AOP** framework like **[PostSharp](http://ruskin-dantra.blogspot.com/2009/03/inotifypropertychanged-made-easier.html)** that does the boiler plate code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this. This type of construct is possible with Aspect oriented programming, but not available in the C# compiler with any production release so far.

There's no general purpose better way to do this, but you might try using a templating engine like Resharpers snippets of VS snippets to make writing these faster.

In some cases, when metadata is available, you can also use code generation to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic properties are an "all or nothing" deal.

All they do is create a backing field, return its value in the get accessor and set its value in the set accessor. If you want to do anything extra, you must define the backing field and implement the get and set manually. There's no way around it.

You may wonder why you even need an automatic property if it doesn't have any logic? Why not just define a public field? But let's say that you define an auto property and other assemblies use your assembly. Now, if you decide to change to manually implemented property to add some logic, the assemblies that use your assembly do NOT have to recompile. If you switch from a field to a property they will break and must be recompiled.

Here is a direct link to my part of my interactive .NET tutorial where I discuss properties in much detail: http://motti.me/s2a

And here is a link to the whole tutorial if your'e interested: http://motti.me/c0

i hope this helps!