# Alternative of Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: c#, .net, aop

Is there any alternative of using Aspect Oriented Programming to inject repetitive code.
Suppose we have a class that contains many properties and if a property get its value changed we would like to log that.

```
class Person 
{
 public string Name
 {
    get{return name;}
    set
    { 
      name = value;
      LogPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  public int Age
  {
    get{return age;}
    set
    { 
      age = value;
      LogPropertyChanged("Age");
    }
   }      
}
```

How would you get rid of repetitive code like security checking, logging and stuff like that without using Aspect Oriented Programming.

Comment: What's wrong with aspect-oriented programming? It sounds like that's exactly what you want.

Comment: @TimS. Nothing wrong, I just don't want to use an external framework.

Comment: @anouar.bag you can implement it yourself without using a framework. just google a bit.

Comment: Isn't AO Programing only a paradigm? What external framework are you refering too? Or do you mean without adding that "LogPropertyChanged" method?

Comment: @LightStriker Sure but we still need to write some code or rely to third-party framework. I'm running out of time and can't spend a lot of effort learning stuff I'm not familiar with nor rely to external dependencies so I was wondering if we can achieve such kind of thing using pure OO(design patterns, inheritance).

Comment: @anouar.bag: Alright... But what is the ultimate goal here? Beside some personal preference for one design patterns over another...

Comment: @LightStriker The goal is to have a clean code, but this can't be reached easily due to a restrictive team policy of using frameworks

Comment: @anouar.bag "Clean code" is never a goal, it's a side objective at best. A goal is to make the code do something. I know coders would prefer to have ages to polish a page of code and make it "perfect", but it's never the case. First, make it work. After that... we will see. Design paradigm are tools to make your life easier, not harder. If a paradigm is giving you trouble, dump it. When you choose a paradign, it's not to make things "nicier", it's to make things "easier".

Comment: @LightStriker It's a goal if it will save your company a lot of money that would be spend on maintenance; let's say that make it work was the first step and it was accomplished with success, now we need to make it easy to maintain.

Comment: "due to a restrictive team policy of using frameworks" So I guess you won't be using the .NET framework?  Has your team implemented its own C# compiler?  And I suppose you don't rely on Windows either?

Comment: @mbeckish May be a less `restrictive` word than `restrictive` would explain my point of view better than it did.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do something like this

a)  On some parent class of your objects

```
protected void SetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> exp, T value)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)exp.Body;
    //set the actual value
    (body.Member as FieldInfo).SetValue(this, value);

    //do some logging, locking, etc. with the field name
    string fieldName = body.Member.Name;
}
```

b)  On your objects

```
private int age;
public int Age
{
    get
    { 
        return age; 
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(() => age, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could of course implement all of that yourself, but then again, Why reinvent the wheel? Apart from injection code at compile time there's nothing you can really do.

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking at a way to do that a few months back. Here's some research I've done.

The idea is to do a static initializer which will bootstrap and inject MSIL code (for example, wrapping functions on runtime for logging) via reflection. A similar concept is already available in postsharp, but that is licensed software which is not suitable for my environment.

These following links can help get you started.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0x241a0.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkattributestutorialanchor3

It really pushes the boundaries of the .net platform, I haven't gotten around to implementing it yet for my work.

Comment: Helpful links, but I'm looking for some design tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own code snippets to simplify the creation of such repeating code patterns. There are different free code snippet editors around. I'm using [Snippy](http://snippy.codeplex.com/). In an answer given to another question on SO I'm explaining such a code snippet (it creates properties for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface): https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317280/880990

Comment: The point is not writing duplicated code but maintaining it

Answer (score 0):

If you donot want to use an external runtime-framework you can use a **[modell driven approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture)** - you have a business-modell in a computer readable format 
(i.e. xml oder use the database-definitions) and have some codegenerator to generate the required sourcecode out of the the modell using code-templates.

The dotnet-typed-datasets are an example of modell-bassed programing. the c# dataset-sourcecode is generated from xsd-dataset-modell.

[mygeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) is a software that can generate sourcecode out of a databasemodell using templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do without a third-party tool (for AOP in general) is the **decorator pattern**, but I'm not sure that's going to be a lot of help for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern. Filip's answer (or something like it) is probably the best you can do in C# right now.

Your team policy seems quite restrictive and draconian from what I know about it, but here's another angle to consider what could be a "loophole" in your team policy: there is an [IL manipulation framework known as Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), which has many plugins (one of which handles `INotifyPropertyChanged`, called [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)). During the build process, Fody modifies your compiled assembly, but the *resulting* assembly (i.e. the code that you ship) has no dependency on Fody or the plugin (as opposed to, say, PostSharp or Castle DynamicProxy, where you have to ship PostSharp.dll or Castle.Core.dll with your project).